# Steps required to make a cow kosher for consumption

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Let's say I have a cow and I want to eat it what are the steps according to halachah.

I'm not looking for details just the basics

Something like this

1. Shechita by a certified Shochet
2. Bedika? What is checked? By whom is it checked?
3. Salting or roasting
4. Throw out back half of cow
5. Eat

Comment: It is more practical to reverse steps 3 and 4. Also it is easier to cut out the half-cow into pieces before salting it. Last most people cook the meat before eating it but it is not required.

Comment: 4 is more a practicality - the main thing is to "remove the forbidden fats" from the back half. As this is difficult, many kosher certifiers will just sell the back half to non-Jews, but some will still remove the forbidden bits and keep it

Comment: https://sealk.org/kosher-meat/ — Here’s a good breakdown

Comment: Don't forget to say a beracha!